# Evolving a Pokémon

Tags: pokemon-go

When evolving a Pokémon of the same kind in PokémonGo, do you evolve the high cp or the low cp Pokémon?

For example, there are two female Nidorans, one of 144 and the other of 234 (remember, this is just an example, I'm just throwing out numbers and Pokémon). So, which Nidoran do you evolve into a Nidorina?

Comment: NBN-Alex, my question is not a duplicate....

Comment: I'm sorry, I feel the two are simular since it's getting to the same point. (which is more effective? Evolution at low CP or high CP?) the top answer there would fit your question as well. (Evolve the higher CP so you need less candies/SD for powering up, where as lower CP evolution is wasteful)

Comment: @NBN-Alex has a point. The first paragraph of the question he referred, already states his fact, "When activating the evolution for a caught pokemon, it seems to amplify the CP. Thus it is most beneficial to evolve your pokemon with the highest CP, if you have multiple of the same kind."

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you evolve the one having the higher CP. Think about it, if your Nidorans are added like 50 CP each when they evolve, who gets to have the advantage? Found [this](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2016-07-21-pokemon-go-cp-meaning-explained-how-to-get-the-highest-cp-values-and-create-the-most-powerful-team) in the internet, might help your problem.

Comment: Not necessarily true. You want to evolve the higher IV one. (Roughly, the one that has higher CP, taking into account the degree that the ball has traveled on the top arc.)

Comment: In this situation, we're only given a  difference in CP. Therefore we can assume that its IV's are all same.